# Confusion with que / qui / dont / où

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, prépositions

I'm having trouble with que, qui, dont, and où. For the following sentences, did I choose the correct response? It sometimes seems like these are interchangeable.

1. Twilight est l’histoire d’un vampire  et d’une jeune fille (que / **qui** / dont)  tombent amoureux.
2. C’est un endroit  (que / dont / **où**) tout le monde aime aller.
3. L’homme (que / **dont**  / qui) tu as peur habite  près de chez moi. (avoir peur de = to be afraid of)
4. Le cours (**que** / qui / dont)  je déteste, c’est les mathématiques.
5. Ils ont vu quelqu’un  (**que** / qui / dont)  nous ne connaissons pas.
6. Il n’y a rien (que / dont  / **qui**) fonctionne  dans cette voiture. qui / dont

Comment: It's all correct, and "dont" doesn't work in the last one. It does look a little like homework though, it's not really a question.

Comment: and they are interchangeable in none of your examples. Only the bold replies are possible.

Comment: Vote to delete. There are no examples, no sentences, nothing. Let's delete this.

Comment: Welcome to French Language! Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, it belongs to the French Language community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-rout‌​e-for-a-dissociation-request)

Comment: I asked for closure with the already proposed "unclear what you're asking" motive, but also I disagree with questions being asked with the obvious purpose of having one's homework done for them.

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous, nous ne sommes pas là pour faire tes devoirs... Profitons-en pour travailler ton français.

Il s'agit de pronoms relatifs. En l'occurrence, il ne manque que "quoi", et tu as les 5 pronoms relatifs invariables (qui, que, quoi, dont, où). Les pronoms relatifs servent à introduire une proposition subordonnée relative. principaux usages:

qui: sujet (1.) ou complément d'objet indirect (COI) pour une personne (Twilight est l’histoire d’un vampire de qui une jeune fille tombe amoureuse.

que: complément d'objet direct (COD, 4.)

quoi: relatif à un complément qui est une chose (il est difficile d'expliquer l'utilisation de ce pronom, ce en quoi on pourra plus efficacement donner un exemple. Avec tout ce travail en français, Anonymous a de quoi faire.)

dont: COI (3.)

où: complément circonstanciel de lieu (2.) voire de temps (l'époque où se déroule cette histoire...)